# Unloading data from Snowflake to S3 bucket in xml format

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to unload the data I have in Snowflake to S3 bucket to a file with .xml extension. In reality, the required output in not exactly .xml, but rather comma separated values enclosed in  tag. But I know that currently Snowflake doesn't support unloading data to .xml format, so seems like if I create a file format with .xml type and try to run COPY INTO it just won't work.
So I am now trying to understand how can I do it some other way. I have a stored procedure on javascript which select required data and stores it as a formatted string (including xml tags). Is it possible to load this string into the .xml file on S3 (file doesn't exist, I need to create it) using just snowflake javascript? Are there any other possible options that can help me to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a string to a file by defining a File Format that specifies absolutely no formatting - no column or row delimiters, no headers, etc.:

```
create or replace temporary stage MY_TEMP_STAGE;
 
create or replace procedure WRITE_STRING()
returns string
language javascript
execute as caller
as
$$
    var xml = `<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>`;
  
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
    {
        sqlText: "copy into @MY_TEMP_STAGE/MY_XML.xml from (select $1 from VALUES (?))  file_format = (format_name = 'CSV_AS_STRING') single = true;",
        binds:[xml]
    });
  
    stmt.execute();
  
    return "Done";
    
$$;
  
call WRITE_STRING();

select $1 from @MY_TEMP_STAGE (file_format => 'CSV_AS_STRING');

ls @MY_TEMP_STAGE;
```

Comment: That would actually work, but the problem is that files in the bucket must have .xml extension. I tried what you suggested, and even if you are not specifying TYPE in FILE FORMAT, it takes .csv as a TYPE by default, and the files in the bucket have .xml extension...

Comment: Specifying a name is no problem. Refer the the change above. Instead of specifying only the name of the stage in the copy command, provide a file name. Add the option `single=true` and it will write a single file with the specified filename.